# Круг Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Как отрисовывать круг определенного радиуса (в метрах) вокруг текущей позиции в Google Maps API? Позиция круга, соответственно, должна обновляться при каждом обновлении позиции пользователя.

Comment: [Это](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) вам нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте объекты типа **Circle** - **[документация API Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)**. Внесите необходимые изменения в параметры круга, требуемые вам:

```js
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);

  var mapOptions = {
      center: LatLng,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                      

  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

 var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              map: map,
              center: LatLng,
              radius: 100
            });
});
```

*[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459281/how-to-make-circle-on-a-current-location-in-google-map-instead-of-marker)*